# How to find OWL Lite,DL,Full infer rules?

Tags: benchmarking, w3c, owl, triples

I want to find infer rules and rules information.

But, W3C offered examples:
http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-owl-guide-20040210/#owl_sameAs

(infer rule Exam)

```
owl:sameAs(?a, ?b) ^ owl:sameAs(?b, ?c) ^ notEqual(?a, ?b) ^ notEqual(?b, ?c) -> owl:sameAs(?a, ?c)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to perform inference, you need to use something capable of performing reasoning.  You can use a dedicated reasoner, such as Pellet, Hermit, or Fact++, or an rdf database which supports reasoning such as Stardog or OWLIM.

You might also want to checkout the [current version of OWL](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl-overview/) as the document you are referencing is quite old.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Actually, our company make now inference program. So we don't refer to Pellet, Hermit, or Fact++. it is good information but, We don't use it.

Comment: You might consider using one of them, writing a reasoner from scratch is not an easy undertaking, and unless you're in the business of building and selling a reasoner, those implementation details are usually best left to someone else.  But in either case, you really ought to use the current OWL standard.